# Count number of rows for specific ID

Tags: php, mysql

In first table `album` has id and second table `album_details` has `sub_id` which relates from `album` table `id`

[image]

[image]

I need to display count for separate id value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.SUB_ID, A . * , B.CONTENT_VALUE AS detail, 
(SELECT COUNT( ID ) 
FROM album_details WHERE A.ID = B.SUB_ID ) AS count
FROM album AS A, album_details AS B
WHERE A.WEBSITE_ID =  '571710720'
AND A.ID = B.SUB_ID
GROUP BY B.SUB_ID
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Now count column shows 40 for all rows but need to display 'count' 6 for 'id=4', 'count' 3 for 'id=2'

Comment: Remove `DISTINCT` and try

Comment: can you please edit my query

Comment: you need to first approve the edit that is done by some person. till that i am unable to do anything. Just remove `DISTINCT` what's the problem in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is your weapon of choice.

```
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    a.CONTENT_VALUE,
    COUNT(ad.ID)
FROM albums AS a
LEFT JOIN album_details AS ad ON a.ID = ad.SUB_ID
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Feel free to add your `WHERE` before the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT count(`SUB_ID`),SUB_ID from album_details group by `SUB_ID`

Answer (score 1):

Lets say first table is A and second table is B then query will be like this

```
select a.ID, count(b.SUB_ID) AS total
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.SUB_ID
Group by B.SUB_ID.
```

It might help you. If not then ask please.

Answer (score 1):

select count(sub_id) as count1 from album_details where sub_id in(select id from album) WHERE album.WEBSITE_ID =  '571710720'
AND album.ID = album_details.SUB_ID